# Will a Sigma UC lens mount to a Nikon D3100?

Tags: nikon-d3100

Can my Sigma UC zoom be used on my Nikon D3100?
It's a 70-210 4-5.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this lens was offered with several different mounting options, so it depends which version you have.

That said... if you have the f mount model, then it should work.